# Is there a way to disable virtual keyboard in JavaFX for ARM?

Tags: javafx, arm, gluon-mobile

I'm using ARM build of JavaFX from Gluon on my Raspberry Pi. It has Virtual Keyboard enabled, so every time I touch an input field -- the keyboard pops up. Is there a way to disable it? I've tried using `-Dcom.sun.javafx.isEmbedded=false -Dcom.sun.javafx.touch=false -Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard=none` but that has no effect.
I need to do this to replace the default VK with a custom one, that supports different layouts and locales (and looks better, tbh). Right now both of them pop up, overlapping each other.

Comment: why do you want to confuse your users?

Comment: @kleopatra I don't. I'm replacing it with another VK.

Comment: thanks for info - then maybe you should state in your question that you want to replace the default VK with a custom one

Comment: @graynk It seems `com.sun.javafx.virtualkeyboard=none` should hide the default keyboard. Could you file an issue in the [bug tracker](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/8u-dev-rt/issues)?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I'll try to cross-compile my own artifact for OpenJFX to confirm that the issue is with Gluon specifically, and if that's the case, I'll file an issue

Comment: yep, compiled from source, no keyboard pops up unless I specify `Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualkeyboard=javafx`. Filed an issue [here](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/8u-dev-rt/issues/15)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With JavaFX 11 `-Dcom.sun.javafx.virtualKeyboard="none"` works for Gluon builds. For JavaFX8 I haven't found a solution at the time except rebuilding from source.